# Update API url with new location for result

Tags: dynamic, leaflet, api-design

I need to update the coordinates on the API-url depending on where the Map centre is located. I did find a way using 'moveend' and map.getCenter to update the coordinates when moving the map to another location. I also added the missing string parts to get a full API request (dhl_moveend). Everything looks fine when checking console.log. The reason is using DHL API service it only gives you 50 location point for the latlng coordinates used (hardcoded) and I don't want to be restricted to one location only as I want to see different areas as well. But when using the code below I get following error *<!doctype html> "Unexpected token '<'" error, as it's not valid JSON*. I guess the response I'm getting from the API endpoint is an HTML page, not a valid JSON object. What is the error in the code for it to run properly?
No problem when using the hardcoded url but changing to "dhl_moveend" instead of dhl_url gives me the error.

```
    var dhl_moveend;
        map.on('moveend', function(e) {
         dhl_moveend = 'https://api.dhl.com/location-finder/v1/find-by-geo?latitude=' + map.getCenter().lat.toFixed(5) + '&longitude=' + map.getCenter().lng.toFixed(5) + '&providerType=parcel&serviceType=parcel%3Apick-up&radius=100000&limit=100&countryCode=SE';
            console.log(dhl_moveend)
            });
                        

    // API for DHL parcel pickup locations...
    const dhl_url = "https://api.dhl.com/location-finder/v1/find-by-geo?latitude=59.32532&longitude=18.10495&providerType=parcel&serviceType=parcel%3Apick-up&radius=100000&limit=100&countryCode=SE"

    addDHL()
        .then(response => {
            console.log('YESS!');
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
        
    async function addDHL() {
        const response = await fetch(dhl_moveend, {
            method: 'get',
            cache: 'no-store',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'DHL-API-Key': '------'
            },
        });
        const dhl = await response.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using moveend was not such a good idea as you would hit the service limit of api-calls very quickly. I changed the approach to the "overlayadd" instead. By adding the layer to the map it updates the api call with new coordinates. If others looking for something similar then here is my solution....

```
const dhlUrl = '';

function addDHL(dhlUrl) {
return fetch(dhlUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
    cache: 'no-store',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'DHL-API-Key': '--------'
    },
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(dhl => {
        let dhlGeoJson = {};
        dhlGeoJson['type'] = 'FeatureCollection';
        dhlGeoJson['features'] =[];
        
        for (let i = 0; i < dhl.locations.length; i++) {
            let x = dhl.locations[i].place.geo.longitude;
            let y = dhl.locations[i].place.geo.latitude;
            let dhlFeature = {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [x, y]
                },
                'properties': {
                    'x': dhl.locations[i].place.geo.longitude,
                    'y': dhl.locations[i].place.geo.latitude,
                    'address': dhl.locations[i].place.address.streetAddress,
                    'name': dhl.locations[i].name,
                    'postalCode': dhl.locations[i].place.address.postalCode,
                    'city': dhl.locations[i].place.address.addressLocality,
                    'type': dhl.locations[i].location.type,
                }
            };
            dhlGeoJson['features'].push(dhlFeature);
        }
        
         loadDHLdata(dhlGeoJson);
         //console.log(JSON.stringify(dhlGeoJson));

      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
    }
    map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer){
    // add action...
    if (eventLayer.name === 'DHL PickupPoints') {
        const lat = map.getCenter().lat.toFixed(5);
        const lng = map.getCenter().lng.toFixed(5);
        const dhlUrl = "https://api.dhl.com/location-finder/v1/find-by-geo?latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + lng + "&providerType=parcel&serviceType=parcel%3Apick-up&radius=100000&limit=100&countryCode=SE";  
        //console.log(dhlUrl)

        addDHL(dhlUrl).then(response => {
                //handle response
            });     
     }      
    });
```